# jQuery auto resize dropdown width

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, selection

So, I am updating the text of an item in a dropdown via jQuery.  So, when I click Save, it grabs the selected item and changes the text to the new value.  When the new value is longer than the previous text, the dropdown's width correctly increases to fit the longer text.  But, if the selected item had the longest text in the dropdown and the new value is now shorter, the dropdown's width remains the same, instead of decreasing.  So, is there a way to have it auto resize to the longest text in the dropdown?

Just to further explain, here is an example:

The dropdown loads as:

```
|Test Item 1     |
|Test Item 222222|
|Test Item 33    |
```

"Test Item 222222" gets saved as just "Test Item" and I would like the dropdown to look like:

```
|Test Item 1 |
|Test Item   |
|Test Item 33|
```

*EDIT - adding code*

```
if ($("input[class~='ButtonPressed']").val() == "Save") {
    // Save the selected item in the dropdown
    var index = $("#Select").get(0).selectedIndex;
    $("#Select option:eq(" + index + ")").text($("#Name").val());
}
```

Comment: What you're describing should work without having to adjust any widths. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4We5t/

Comment: I should add that this is not working in IE8.  You are correct that it does adjust the widths in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Without any html or css it's not much of a help but what I would suggest is that those elements that have text would be displayed as block or inline-block elements and parent(container) element would not be restricted to specific width, that way they could automatically update.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are talking about.  By dropdown, I mean just a simple html select that contains options.  I am changing the text that is in the one option.

Comment: your first sentence o_O So, I am updating the text of an item in a dropdown via jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all option items and compute width of it's text. Then you can take the most wider and set width of dropdown.

You can use this jQuery plugin for computing text width:

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var html_org = $(this).html();
  var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
  $(this).html(html_calc);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html_org);
  return width;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this using JSFiddle and it seems that you may have some styles applied to you dropdown (?).

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/XQfmL/

This is the code I used in JSFiddle.

```
<select id="s" size="3">
<option value="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" selected="true">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
<option value="aaa">aaa</option>
<option value="aaaa">aaaa</option>
</select>​
<script>
    //FOR YUI
    YUI().use("node", function(Y){
        var nodes = Y.all("#s option");
        Y.later(2000, nodes.item(0), function(){
            nodes.item(0).set("value","a");
            nodes.item(0).setHTML("a");    
        });
    });

    //FOR JQUERY
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#s option").eq(0).val("a").html("a");
    }, 2000);​
</script>
```

After 2 seconds it updates and the dropdown updates it's width automatically.

Comment: Maybe YUI does something that jQuery does not when it changes the text?

Comment: Nope, as simple as JQuery. It uses object.innerHTML and nothing else.

Comment: Well, I am using jQuery.  So, do you know the equivalent to what you're doing in YUI?  I thought it would be what I wrote, but obviously it is not working the same.

Comment: There you go, just delete the YUI stuff and run the jquery only. If works, please mark it as correct, thanks ;)

Comment: Sorry, your code doesn't actually resize, it just changes an option's text.  I can do that.  My issue is that it is not resizing automatically in IE8.